# Assets and WYGWAM 2.7

Tags: assets, wygwam

I see in the latest version of WYGWAM 2.7 that if I use Assets 2.0.4 it will connect my files if I move or rename them.  Does this affect just new files or is it 'clever' enough for all of the past files I've used.

I'm noticing that, even though a folder is indexed, the paths are not updating completely throughout my site.  Most of it is, but not all of it.

What is the best way to search this site to find which assets are not being tracked through Assets 2.0.4 versus going through every entry?  Would Low Search work to search Assets fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mitchell -

Entries will need to be re-saved to take advantage of that feature.

Comment: Any way to convert them or mass re-save them without having to go through 1,000 plus entries?

Comment: Not currently, unfortunately.

Comment: A script for this would be extremely valuable.