# Assets used in WYGWAM fields don't update when file is moved

Tags: assets, wygwam, pixelandtonic, s3, amazon

I'm using [Assets](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/assets) 2.1.4, [WYGWAM](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/wygwam) 2.7.1  and EE 2.5.5.  I have a WYGWAM field, and two assets directories, one local and one Amazon S3.

In the Assets interface, I can move a file from local to S3 just [by dragging](http://pixelandtonic.com/blog/assets2) (awesome!) and any Assets field gets updated automatically, even if it's within Matrix.

However, any images used in the WYGWAM field, they don't get updated to point to the new location (although other questions here like [this](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5779/assets-and-wygwam-2-7) and [this](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/6994/is-it-possible-to-convert-an-ee-file-upload-path-to-assets-s3?rq=1) indicate that they should). In the WYGWAM field, the assets I add are appearing just as raw URLs, not as {assets} tags or anything like that. Sigh.

How can I move files within Assets, and have the WYGWAM fields still point to their proper location?

Thanks.

Comment: as per your first linked question (http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5779/assets-and-wygwam-2-7) I don't suppose the images in the WYGWAM where added to the wygwam before you imlimented S3? If so the tags will need updating in the saved Wygwam contents to asset tags... A good test would be to add a new image to local via Assets and add to a Wygwam. Save it then move the asset to S3, does the new image update where to existing one's dont?

Comment: No, they were added after I implemented both folders.